# Question about the proper interpratation of integral notation

Tags: integration, notation

The book I am using defines the integral $I_N = \int_{-N}^{N}f(x)dx$ and then wants to show that if f(x) is a moderately decreasing function then the sequence of these integrals is a Cauchy sequence.

It then states that given M > N, $\quad$  $|{I_M - I_N}| \leq |\int_{N \leq |x| \leq M} f(x)dx|$

I am just a little unsure of how I should read this integral notation involving the absolute value of x being between two integers.

Thinking about it on a 2-d plane it would seem to suggest that $$\int_{N \leq |x| \leq M} f(x)dx = \int_{N}^{M}f(x)dx + \int_{-M}^{-N}f(x)dx$$

is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you familiar with the Lebesgue integral?

Comment: I am not unfortunately, although I am aware that it is a concept of an integral that differs from that of the Reimann integral. Also, thank you for your detailed response.

Answer (score 1):

You are entirely correct.

In the context of the Riemann integral on $\mathbb{R}$, the notation
$$\int_{N \le |x| \le M} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x $$
can be a little disconcerting—such integrals are typically defined over intervals in terms of Riemann sums.  In this context, you are correct to presume that if $x$ is a real variable, then
$$ \int_{N \le |x| \le M} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
:= \int_{-M}^{-N} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{N}^{M} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x. $$

More generally, however, we might be better served by considering the integral as being defined over a more arbitrary *set*, rather than on an interval.  There is far too much theory to get into here, but this is (perhaps) most naturally understood in the context of the [Lebesgue integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LebesgueIntegral.html).  This notion also appears (as you have suggested) in the context of multivariable integration.  For example,
$$ \iint_{R} f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}A $$
is common notation for a integral (Riemann or otherwise) over a region $R$ in two-dimensional Euclidean space.  In either case, the notation can be interpreted as
$$ \int_{N \le |x| \le M} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x
:= \int_{R} f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x, $$
where $R$ is the set
$$ R = \{x : N \le |x| \le M\}. $$